# orika SourceCodeContext.getInstance StuckThreadMaxTime

Tags: orika

> > <Apr 1, 2021 3:39:57,236 PM ICT> <[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' has been busy for "636"
> > seconds working on the request "Http Request Information:
> > weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl@76dfaa35[POST
> > /digx/cmcb/v1/topup] ", which is more than the configured time
> > (StuckThreadMaxTime) of "600" seconds in "server-failure-trigger".
> > Stack trace: java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
> > java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
> > java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)
> > java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.SourceCodeContext.getInstance(SourceCodeContext.java:262)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.impl.generator.MapperGenerator.build(MapperGenerator.java:73)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.buildMapper(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1480)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.registerClassMap(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1256)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.impl.DefaultMapperFactory.registerClassMap(DefaultMapperFactory.java:1269)
> > ma.glasnost.orika.metadata.ClassMapBuilder.register(ClassMapBuilder.java:774)
> > com.cmcb.rest.mapping.DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter$OrikaMapper.lambda$registerExcludedFields$0(DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter.java:93)
> > com.cmcb.rest.mapping.DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter$OrikaMapper$$Lambda$72/387331492.accept(Unknown
> > Source)
> > java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
> > java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
> > com.cmcb.rest.mapping.DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter$OrikaMapper.registerExcludedFields(DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter.java:88)
> > com.cmcb.rest.mapping.DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter$OrikaMapper.map(DefaultOrikaObjectsConverter.java:101)
> > com.chipmong.digx.app.payments.assembler.mobile.TopUpAssembler.toDomain(TopUpAssembler.java:40)
> > com.chipmong.digx.app.payments.assembler.mobile.TopUpAssembler.toPinLessDomain(TopUpAssembler.java:49)
> > com.chipmong.digx.app.payments.service.mobile.TopUpService.lambda$14(TopUpService.java:206)
> > com.chipmong.digx.app.payments.service.mobile.TopUpService$$Lambda$71/1250090818.execute(Unknown
> > Source)